# MVC - Handling unterminated string literal for new line

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC view am having the below piece of code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@foreach (var item in Model.Test)
{
<text> jsFunction(@item.someValue);  </text>
}
</script>
```

Where am calling the  Javascript function based on the data i get from model dynamically.

For Example At run time it is rendered like below based on the model data

```
jsFunction("Works Fine");  
jsFunction("works Fine");
```

Which correctly calls my javascript function

But in case of a new line getting **"unterminated string literal"** because of the new line

```
jsFunction("not working
with new line");
```

What is the best way to handle this Scenario

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the best way to handle this Scenario

Use a JSON serializer which will ensure that the value passed to your javascript function is properly escaped:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@foreach (var item in Model.Test)
{
    <text>jsFunction(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.someValue)));</text>
}
</script>
```

or if you update your `jsFunction` to take an array instead of a single item you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var values = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Test));
    jsFunction(values);
</script>
```

and then loop through the normal javascript array that will be passed to your function.

P.S: Don't worry if Razor Intellisense is putting a red squiggle around this code. Visual Studio Intellisense in Razor views doesn't work well. Just ignore the warning and run your application and observe the properly generated code.

Comment: HTML.Raw()  adds "" to my HTML which is displayed in UI. How do i avoid that ! Thanks

Comment: Json.Encode is returning "quote". how do i avoid that being displayed in screen ?

Comment: You know what. You rock. your P.S: was my mistake. Thanks @Darin :)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to create a helper or something:

```
@* declared at top of razor page *@
@helper jsFunction(String str)
{
    str = (str ?? String.Empty).Trim().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\n");
    @:jsFunction("@Html.Raw(str)");
}

@* example usage *@
foreach (var item in Model.Test)
{
    @jsFunction(@item.Comment)
}
```

That would perform sanitization on the string to make it convert `\n` in to the JavaScript counter-part `\\n`. You may also include exceptions for quotation marks (turn `"` into `\"`, etc.)

The **better** alternative is to use something like JSON.NET though:

```
<text>jsFunction(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.Serialize(@item.Comment)))</text>
```

That would make it completely safe to JavaScript (and handle the exceptions for you).

Comment: HTML.Raw()  adds "" to my HTML which is displayed in UI. How do i avoid that ! Thanks

Comment: @user2067567: In which call? the helper method or JsonConvert?

Comment: JSON is causing the Quot which is sent to UI!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
jsFunction(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.Comment)))
```

I think this should solve your issue.

Comment: yes you are right just forgot to place the Json.Encode on the item